# React update on window resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a grid with some images and want to update the number of columns on certain widths. 
For example:

- width > 960px: 3 columns
- width > 660px: 2 columns
- width < 660px: 1 column

I've created a function to update the number of rows, but how can I rerender the grid without pressing F5?

My states:

```
this.state = {
  numberOfColumns: 3,
  breakpointSm: 660px,
  breakpointMd: 960px,
};
```

My function:

```
getNumberOfColumns(){
  let smallDevices = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: " + this.state.breakpointSm + ")" );
  let mediumDevices = window.matchMedia( "(max-width:" + this.state.breakpointMd + ")" );
  let columns;

  if (smallDevices.matches) {
    columns = 1;
  } else if (mediumDevices.matches){
    columns = 2;
  } else {
    columns = 3;
  }
  this.setState({
    numberOfColumns: columns
  });
}
```

Component will mount:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.getNumberOfColumns();
}
```

Comment: Why not do this entirely in css?

Comment: Do it simple
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp
or 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: I've create a masonry grid layout with flexbox. Therefore I've to set the height of the container. I've created a function to calculate the height of the container (height of the items * number of rows). Thats the reason why I can't use plain css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple way to slove the issue is to added an event listner on resize or simply use a plain css what this code actually do is to force a re-render every time the window size change

```
    getNumberOfColumns() {
        let columns;
        if(window.innerWidth === this.state.breakpointSm) {
          columns = 1;
        } else if(window.innerWidth === this.state.breakpointMd) {
         columns = 2;

        }else{
       columns = 3;
             }
         this.setState({
             numberOfColumns: columns
                    });
      }


componentDidMount() {
  this.getNumberOfColumns();
window.addEventListener("resize", this.getNumberOfColumns.bind(this));
}

 componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.getNumberOfColumns.bind(this));
  }
```

and in the worst case scenario if nothing work , you can use `this.forceUpdate()` but try to avoid it as much as you can

i didnt test it yet , but i hope this will help

Comment: .bind(this) creates a new function

Comment: if he dont use .bind(this) , it will create a bug and on the componentWillunmount will remove the original event listner , a known pattern to slove the issue in react is to create a new instance of the function

Comment: It doesn't work.. I've still to press F5 to refresh the page

Comment: window.addEventListener("resize", this.getNumberOfColumns.bind(this)); will add the eventListener to a fn1 and window.removeEventListener("resize", this.getNumberOfColumns.bind(this)); will remove the eventListener to fn2

https://gist.github.com/Restuta/e400a555ba24daa396cc

Comment: store this somewhere `let fn1= this.getNumberOfColumns.bind(this)`
then add do `window.addEventListener("resize", fn1);` and ``window.removeEventListener("resize", fn1);``

Comment: @Jonas Niedermair i did edit my answer can you test it and let me know

Answer (score 1):

I would advice using CSS for it, it approach seems more approprate for me. Re-rendering component to do something that can be achieved with media queries in CSS is an overkill IMHO.

CSS:

```
//for medium screens
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    //for tiny screens
    @media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    }
    //for big screens
    @media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   }
}
```